# how to register app to handle QR code scanned from mobile camera in xamarin forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, qr-code

I am trying to make a feature where if user scans a QR code from mobile camera or any other QR code scanning app it should show user that they have the app installed and if they want to open the app.

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Android:**

Add below line above the **MainActivity.cs**

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
DataScheme = "https", DataHost = "YourDomainName", AutoVerify = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
```

**OnCreate**

```
var url = Intent?.Data?.ToString();
```

and pass it on **load application**

**iOS:**

Enable Associated domain for identifier on apple developer account
Regenerate development and distribution certificate if needed. Download and install

Create file called **apple-app-site-association** and add it to root of your domain

in **apple-app-site-association:**

```
 {
       "applinks": {
         "apps": [],
         "details": [
           {
             "appID": "YourAppId.YourBundleIdentifier",
             "paths": [ "*"]
           }
         ]
       }
}
```

in **Entitlements.plist:**
Enable Associated domain and add "applinks:domainName"

in **appdelegate:**

```
 public override bool ContinueUserActivity(UIApplication application, NSUserActivity userActivity, UIApplicationRestorationHandler completionHandler)
    {
        if (userActivity.ActivityType == "NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb")
        {
            var url = userActivity.WebPageUrl.AbsoluteString;
            ((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current).AppLinkRequest(url);
            return true;
        }
        return base.ContinueUserActivity(application, userActivity, completionHandler);
    }

    public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
    {
        if (url.AbsoluteString != null)
        {
            ((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current).AppLinkRequest(url.AbsoluteString);
            return true;
        }
        return base.OpenUrl(app, url, options);
    }
```

**App.xaml.cs**

in ctor

```
if (QRcodeURL != null)
{
// Android Implementation for handling QR code scanning
// Handle code
}
```

method

```
public void AppLinkRequest(string url)
{
// iOS Implementation for handling QR code scanning
// Handle code
}
```